# Use PHP's $_POST values in a JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using Morris JS to display a Line Chart.

I have a JavaScript file with static values

```
$(function() {

  Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',

      data: 
    [
        { year: '2015', a: 20 },
        { year: '2016', a: 25 },
        { year: '2017', a: 40 },
    ],

    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Equity Partners ']

});
```

I was expecting I could do

```
$(function() {

  Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',

      data: 
    [
        { year: '2015', a: <?php echo $_POST["AmericanIndian_EP"];  ?> },
        { year: '2016', a: <?php echo $_POST["AmericanIndian_A"];  ?> },
        { year: '2017', a: <?php echo $_POST["AmericanIndian_C"];  ?> },
    ],

    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Equity Partners ']

});
```

to get the PHP values I have used PHP's POST on after submitting a form and display it on the JavaScript table data. But, it throws an error on my PHP input.

So basically, I would just like to know how I could input PHP in my JavaScript file?

Comment: What is the relation between the file/code that handles the submitted form and the Javascript?  If you are redirecting to a file that includes the Javascript, you could send your values along in the querystring and pull them from there using Javascript.  Once you leave the process that handles the form, those POST values don't exist.

Comment: If any of the provided solution work for you, then please accept it.

Comment: @mega6382 Hi. I tried all available solutions here but I may just have a lack of knowledge on manipulating their given codes to make it work for mine. Instead, I did it by PHP.

Comment: @SimoneWalter OK, then post your solution and accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form using javascript

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#form').attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      data : $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        // data here should have the new values for your chart
        console.log('form submitted.');
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the expected data for `Morris.Line`, you need to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to supply the entire object to javascript so that everything is automatically escaped for use by JS.

```
...
element: 'morris-line-chart',
data: <?php json_encode(
[
    ['year'=>'2015','a'=>$_POST["AmericanIndian_EP"]],
    ['year'=>'2016','a'=>$_POST["AmericanIndian_A"]],
    ['year'=>'2017','a'=>$_POST["AmericanIndian_C"]]
]
); ?>,
xkey: 'year',
...
```

Comment: I tried this but still returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Comment: I gave the code another go but this time it displayed no error LMAO