# Display values on a JavaScript Line Chart using PHP's $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to do an exercise for school purposes. I'm using Morris JS to display my line chart and use PHP to post values from the table. Here's the table input:

[CLICK ME](https://simonewalter.000webhostapp.com/AmericanBusinessAssociation/SimoneWalterMacatangay/pages/form.php)

When you click the Submit button, it will display the values inputted and the line chart provided by Morris JS. The line chart currently displays static values. What I wanted to happen is, get  the values from the values inputted from the table.

[HERE WAS MY PREVIOUS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733796/use-phps-post-values-in-a-javascript-file?noredirect=1#comment80423178_46733796)

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>American Indian/Alaska Native</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_EP" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

PHP Code Snippet:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>American Indian/Alaska Native</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_EP" value="<?php echo $_POST["AmericanIndian_EP"];  ?>" disabled="" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Morris JavaScript Code Snippet:

```
$(function() {
  Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data:  [
      { year: '2015', a: 20, b: 5, c: 30,  d: 35,  e: 14 },
      { year: '2016', a: 25, b: 8, c: 42,  d: 30,  e: 9 },
      { year: '2017', a: 40, b: 10, c: 49,  d: 20,  e: 11 },
    ],
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    labels: ['Equity Partners ', 'Non Equity ', 'Associate ', 'Counsel ', 'Other Lawyer']
  });
```

I was expecting I could input a PHP code on the variables but it does not work. For example:

```
$(function() {
  Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data: <?php json_encode([
      ['year'=>'2015','a'=>$_POST["AmericanIndian_EP"]],
      ['year'=>'2016','a'=>$_POST["AmericanIndian_A"]],
      ['year'=>'2017','a'=>$_POST["AmericanIndian_C"]]
    ]); ?>,
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Equity Partners ']
  });
```

Please, help. Thank you!